# window.print() opens two print dialogs on FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, printing

Yes, as the name suggests, I am getting two print dialogs on Chrome latest and FF latest.

The code I'm using is:

```
var $printButton = $('#print_button');

if ($printButton) {
    $printButton.on('click', function () {
        window.print();
    })
}
```

The second dialog only opens when I have actioned the first dialog (print or cancel), if that helps.

EDIT:

After narrowing it down to an issue with my callback, I put a `console.log('hello');` in the script and found that it was calling twice on refresh.

My script file was being included twice somewhere on the page. Thank you legacy code :)

Thanks for the advice everyone.

Comment: `if ($printButton)` will **always** be true; the `if` statement is unnecessary.

Comment: Also what exactly does the markup for this button look like (the HTML)?

Comment: The script is generic for all pages, and the print button is only on one of many pages, that's the reason for the if (but it might be better to have a separate bundle).

    `<button id="print_button" class="button primary">Print</button>`

Is the HTML for the button

Comment: are you accidentally adding the on click code twice? check the print button in the developer tools element inspector to see what events are attached to it, make sure YOUR click event is only attached once (jquery has a habit of doing odd stuff, so don't worry if other click events are added to the button, just click events that refer to your code)

Comment: Agree with @JaromandaX I think the code is working fine.  Since you are saying that this code is in a generic place, please make sure it is not getting executed twice.

Comment: I added a breakpoint for 'click' events in Chrome and it will break when I click, then if I continue it'll open the double print dialogue, but then after I close those I get another break presumably from the same click event. Very weird

Comment: I just changed my markup to `<a href="javascript:window.print();" id="print_button" class="button primary">Print</a>` to test, and it only opens one dialogue. So there's definitely an issue with my listener/my callback

Comment: did you check the developer tools inspector to check what events are added to `$printButton` - maybe chrum doesn't have that feature, use firefox, click the **ev** next to the element in inspector to see the events added to the element

Comment: I couldn't see that in Chrome, but I'll remember to use Firefox in future. The problem is solved - I edited it into the main question. Thanks everyone!